# Different behaviour with and without Symfony's response system

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, webdav

I'd like to be able to manage WebDAV directories (and even reimplement the way files are read and written) in Symfony. To do so I found SabreDAV, which is itself a framework with all the basic classes required.

My problem is, while it's quite easy to get a WebDAV server running using SabreDAV alone, it doesn't work that well when I use Symfony.

Without Symfony, it boils down to:

> $server = new DAV\Server($rootDirectory);
>
> $server->exec();

And I can use cadaver to access my directory.

More here: http://code.google.com/p/sabredav/wiki/GettingStarted

I tried to do the same in my controller with Symfony, using:

> return new Response($server->exec());

but for some reason cadaver doesn't have access to the folder.
I guess I'm missing something about the way responses work in Symfony, but what? SabreDAV uses its own system of http requests and responses, but if (as I presume) Symfony doesn't mess with superglobal variables such as $_SERVER, this shouldn't be an issue.

About requests and responses in Symfony: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html#requests-and-responses-in-symfony

Here's what I did; it's a bit slow and there must be a better way, but I'll make do with that for the moment:
Controller.php :

```
$path=(__DIR__.'/../../../../web/public/');
$path=realpath($path);
$publicDir= new \MyClasses\FS\MyDirectory($path);
$server = new \Sabre\DAV\Server($publicDir);
$server->setBaseUri('/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/');


{
  $SyRequest = Request::createFromGlobals();
  $_server=$SyRequest->server->all();
  $_post=$SyRequest->request->all();
}


{
  $SaRequest=new \MyClasses\HTTP\Request($_server,$_post); 
  $resourceStream=false;
  $SaRequest->setBody($SyRequest->getContent($resourceStream),$resourceStream);
}


{
  $server->httpRequest=$SaRequest;
  $SaResponse=new \MyClasses\HTTP\Response();
  $server->httpResponse=$SaResponse;
  $server->exec();
}


{
  $content=ob_get_clean();
}


{
  $SyResponse=new Response($content,http_response_code(),headers_list());
}

return $SyResponse;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$server->exec();
```

Doesn't really return anything. It attempts to set headers itself, and stream the output to `php://output` (indeed, with the built-in request/response system).

If you want to embed SabreDAV into symfony, the most proper way to solve this is to subclass both `Sabre\HTTP\Request` and `Sabre\HTTP\Response`, and set these in the server (setting the `->httpRequest` and `->httpResponse` properties) before calling `->exec`.

Your overridden request/response objects should then map to symfony's equivalents.

I don't know enough about symfony to tell you if they map cleanly and easily though, and I imagine it will in practice be simpler to try to work around symfony's system (although from an architectural standpoint, it will not be the most proper).

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried this more or less, but the status code was missing. Thanks for SabreDAV by the way.